# Cannot create new Oracle ODBC Datasource

Tags: oracle, odbc, driver

I try to add new Data Source in ODBC Administrator but I get an error:

> *Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator failed*
>
> The setup routines for the Oracle in OraClient11g_home1 ODBC driver could not be accessed. Please reinstall the driver.

Reinstalling Oracle does not help.

Other drivers (include stone-age "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle") work well. I can also use existing ODBC data sources I added earlier times, so the driver works well. I get the error only when I try to add a new data source or try to re-configure an existing one.

I found this solution https://serverfault.com/questions/555972/cannot-create-oracle-odbc-source-on-64bit-windows-7 but it does not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was caused by some manual edits in my Registry. It should be like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\Oracle in OraClient11g_home1]
"APILevel"="1"
"CPTimeout"="60"
"ConnectFunctions"="YYY"
"Driver"="C:\\oracle\\product\\11.2\\Client_x64\\bin\\sqora32.dll"
"DriverODBCVer"="03.51"
"FileUsage"="0"
"Setup"="C:\\oracle\\product\\11.2\\Client_x64\\bin\\sqoras32.dll"
"SQLLevel"="1"
```

DLL for `Driver` is "sqora32.dll" whereas DLL for `Setup` it is "sqora**s**32.dll"